# how to display database record in gird line

Tags: 8, database, theming

[image]I have created custom module to display some records from database ,i need to print the records as grid line how i can achieve this ,

```
    <?php

namespace Drupal\uniview8_defaulters\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Database;
class uniview8DefaultersController extends ControllerBase {

static function getAll() {
    $userCurrent = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($userCurrent->id());
    $uid = $user->getUsername();
if($uid == "admin")
{

$result = db_query('select name from {users_field_data} as u left join {uv_payu_response} as uv on u.name=uv.payu_udf2 where uv.payu_udf2   IS NULL');

    return $result;
}
  }


  public function userview() {

    $content = array();

  $rows = array();
   // $headers = array(t('MEMBER ID'));

    foreach ($entries = $this->getAll() as $entry) {

      $rows[] = array_map('Drupal\Component\Utility\SafeMarkup::checkPlain', (array) $entry);
    }

$len=sizeof($rows);
drupal_set_message(t("$len"));
drupal_set_message(t("$rows"));
foreach($rows as $res)
{
$content['list'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
       '#markup' =>'<strong>'.$res .'  </strong>'
 );
 } 
    return $content;
  }

}
```

> EXPECTED OUTPUT

DEFAULTERS MEMBER ID:

EMP1
EMP2
EMP3
EMP4
EMP5
EMP6
EMP7
EMP8
EMP9
EMP10
......
......

Comment: use #type => 'table' provide a header as well as row data

Comment: i dont want to display  the records as table , i need  to show all records  as GRID LINE ,